# What is causing the "error: attribute mapbox_styleUrl not found"?

Tags: java, android, navigation, mapbox

I keep getting the error "attribute mapbox_styleUrl not found" when trying to implement the Navigation SDK of Mapbox into my project.
I think it has to do with the migration of the Map SDK to 7.0.0 where they removed the mapbox_styleUrl XML attribute, but I'm unable to find a way to fix this.

I'm not using the styleUrl in any of my code. I leave the map style in my layout default and set it in onMapReady.

This is the complete error:

```
Android resource linking failed
Output:  C:\Users\Jonas\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\mapbox-android-navigation-ui-0.26.0.aar\0ea5c6919c35d65de36f46fe7fce49d7\res\layout\navigation_view_layout.xml:10: error: attribute mapbox_styleUrl (aka com.fishdev.planmyrun:mapbox_styleUrl) not found.
error: failed linking file resources.
```

Complete `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fishdev.planmyrun"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    //  Mapbox dependencies
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:7.0.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-annotation-v7:0.4.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.26.0'
```

}

My MapView in layout:

```
<com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLat="50.87485515"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLng="4.707931288875566"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="11"
        />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I happened to come across the exact same issue today whilst migrating an Android app from Mapbox Android SDK `6.5.0` to `7.0.0`.

I too had no `mapbox_styleUrl` usages in my code, so I spent a little time scratching my head before I noticed that the error references `mapbox-android-navigation-ui-0.26.0` which appears to be utilising this attribute (removed in Mapbox Android SDK `7.0.0`). Taking a deeper look into the [Mapbox Navigation Android repository](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android), I noticed that the [latest commit](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-navigation-android/commit/c4a30f2a985a34decdb4838fd6a055f54ecbed68#diff-e6675d661ba806d6f787db3d69e286a1) (*from ~6 hours ago*) of `mapbox-android-navigation-ui` had brought everything up to date with the Mapbox Android SDK `7.0.0`.

Since these fixes had not been packaged in an official release as yet, I added the latest snapshot release to my project by updating my dependencies via Gradle:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-navigation-ui:0.27.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

I sincerely hope that saves you a headache!

Answer (score 0):

make sure u are settig the content view to the correct layout

ie: my line on the set content view was set to mainActivity istead of MapsActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Mapbox.getInstance(MapsActivity.this, getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token));
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
```